# MYSQL #1241 Error Message

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to pull data from a table between two dates and sum it to get one number.  My code is as follows:

```
SELECT Total_Rode, SUM(Total_Rode)
FROM Sales 
WHERE Sales.Sales_Date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(Budget.Budget_Date, INTERVAL 364 DAY) 
AND DATE_SUB(Budget.Budget_Date, INTERVAL 357 DAY) 
AND Sales.Company = '98'
GROUP BY Total_Rode
```

I keep getting the error message "Database Error: problem executing query. (Operand should contain 1 column(s)) #1241

Comment: Shouldn't you be joining the `Budget` table?

Comment: Could you create a quick SQL Fiddle to help us see your DDL?

Answer (score 0):

You missed to join `Budget` Table

```
SELECT Total_Rode, SUM(Total_Rode)
FROM Sales 
join Budget 
on sales.commoncolumn = Budget.commoncolumn
WHERE Sales.Sales_Date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(Budget.Budget_Date, INTERVAL 364 DAY) 
AND DATE_SUB(Budget.Budget_Date, INTERVAL 357 DAY) 
AND Sales.Company = '98'
GROUP BY Total_Rode
```